# Parsing mbox file in java

Tags: java, email, parsing, mbox, mime4j

I downloaded a mailing list archive from `SourceForge`. Mailing lists are each automatically archived to a mbox file. So now I need to extract the body from `mbox file` using `Java`. Is there a `mailbox parser` in `Java`?

Thanks